# Array issue with a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have an issue with syntax in a query

This works

```
$db->execute_query("UPDATE table SET order=2,active_status=3 WHERE id=? AND uid=?",array($id,$uid));
```

But this does not. It's because of the array

```
$db->execute_query("UPDATE table SET order=?,active_status=3 WHERE id=? AND uid=?",array($shoid,$id,$uid));
```

I also tried something like

```
$db->execute_query("UPDATE table (`order`) WHERE id=? AND uid=? VALUES (?)",array($id,$uid,$shoid));
```

But this is not working either.

The error I get is this

```
Query failed : UPDATE orsil_quote (`order`) WHERE id='38' AND uid='115' VALUES ('49')
```

The problem is '49' if i can remove ' from 49 in the query. this will work like this , im sure

```
$db->execute_query("UPDATE table SET order=?,active_status=3 WHERE id=? AND uid=?",array($shoid,$id,$uid));
```

Comment: Post your full php Code

Comment: it is a lot of code, and most of it useless, if you want to know what does $shoid has, its just like $shoid='40' (the last id) i will edit to paste the error, throw so you can see

Comment: thanks :) that was what i meant (sorry for the sort comentary, i was on the mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query didn't worked because of the `order` keyword rest queries are not correct, like update query doesn't take `VALUES` i.e. used in your third query.

TRY

```
 db->execute_query("UPDATE table SET `order`=?,active_status=3 WHERE id=? AND  
                   uid=?",array($shoid,$id,$uid))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `order`=2,active_status=3 WHERE (id, uid) IN (?)
```

Generate the pairs of `(id, uid)` like `(id1, uid1), (id1, uid2), (id2, uid3), etc...` and pass it to query.

Comment: order is a variable number sent in the array as $shoid, check the question again

Comment: @MonchoChavez Then you have to fire multiple query for each set of values